# Regex for splitting reference string into its components

Tags: javascript, regex

**Updated the question with more proper example strings**

There are strings like this:

```
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016) Example: A string title. Publication. 12:123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC, et al. (2016) Example: A string title? Publication. 12:123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication 2016; 12: 123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication 2016; 12: 123
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Publication 12, 123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Publication 12 (6), 123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication. 2016 June;12(6):123-54. Ignore this
```

Now I'm trying to extract the parts of them to get the result:

```
1: Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC || Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC, et al.
2: 2016
3: Example: A string title? || Example: A string title
4: Publication
5: 12
6: 123-54 || 123
```

This is what I get so far:

```
/([\w-]+ [A-Z]{1,3}(?:, [\w-]+ [A-Z]{1,3})*(?:, et al\.)*)|\((\d{4})\)?|([\w:]+[\w ]+(?=\.|\?|$))|(\d+(?=:))|([\d-]+)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/wB3wU4/2

Thanks to *anubhava* and *Jan* so far.

But with this I don't get all *Publication*, in the last string I would like to ignore everything after the pagenumber and I need to ignore the bracket in front of the pagenumber (if there is one).

The second problem for me is how to do a proper processing with this data, as the position of the matches could be different. Example: Normally match[2] should be the `year`, but for the 3rd string, that wouldn't be the case. So the results get mixed up :-(

Comment: Are there **any** constants? `Example`, `12`, `123`?

Comment: @ClasG No, all things shown in the results are variable, no constants.

Comment: Is `Publication` (or the variable content) always a single word, or can it be a sentence?

Comment: Can be a sentence.

Comment: Please stop editing the question, invalidating the existing answers as you go. This makes voting and answering nigh on impossible. If you have a new question with new constraints, ask a new question with those new constraints. No fair moving the goal while people are trying to make a shot :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm sorry. I tried just to clarify the post and give better example data without changing the question at all. Before that I posted a new question, but I was told to close it, because it is a duplicate of this question. Everything seems to be wrong :-)

Comment: You're not going to get anywhere doing it this way. You've made it specific using punctuation and some obscure fraction's of literals. What makes it untenable is that you've mixed `\w` and `\d` with it. It's better to key on the fractions of literals and the punctuation in an optional positional way. Or, even better use known keywords you want/don't want to help the split. Get rid of the alternations and string it out optionally in a sequential way. This insures a basic %95 hit rate without false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time for me to throw the hat in the ring. This is what I came up with:

```
^(.*?)\s*(?:\(((?:19|20)\d\d)\)|:)[\s:]*(.*?[?.!])\s*([\w\s]+?)\.?\s*(?:((?:19|20)\d\d)(?:\s+\w+)?)?[.;\s]*(\d+)\s*(?:\(\d+\))?[,:\s]+(\d+(?:-\d+)?)[^\d]*$
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wB3wU4/5).

Because of the complexity I won't try to explain every bit of the regex here, but check the link to regex101 and you'll see an explanation in the right pane.

I'll try to explain the gist of it however. It depends on a few things that I'm unsure are facts, but...

From the beginning of the string

- the song title must end with a year in parentheses **or** a colon (`:`). It's limiting the match of the year to the twentieth or twenty first century.

Then from the back:

- there can be no digits in the *ignore*-part
- the last capture is always in the form `number dash number` where the to latter parts are optional.
- the `12` part is a number, optionally preceded by a `.`, `;` or a space, and followed by an optional number inside parentheses. The parentheses can optionally be preceded by spaces. This whole part is then followed by at least one `,`, `:` or space.
- the `12` part is optionally preceded by a year, which in turn optionally is followed by a month (thrown away).

Between the start and the end of the string, from the first part, a "sentence" is captured **ending with a punctuation** (`.`, `?` or `!`). After that comes the second "sentence" - the `Publication`part.

This gives us the following capture groups:

1. Title 1
2. (Optionally) Year
3. Title 2
4. Sentence `Publication`
5. (Optionally) Year
6. `12` part
7. `123-54` part

I.e year is either in group 2 **or** 5.

It *feels* quite fragile, but it may get the job done for you. ;)

**Edit**

I've made a JS snip to illustrate: (use full screen)

```js
var theStrings = [
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016) Example: A string title. Publication. 12:123-54',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC, et al. (2016) Example: A string title? Publication. 12:123-54',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication 2016; 12: 123-54',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication 2016; 12: 123',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Publication 12, 123-54',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Publication 12 (6), 123-54',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication. 2016 June;12(6):123-54. Ignore this',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2050) Example: A string title. Placeholder. 55:123-54',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC, et al. (2016) Example: A string title? Word. 22:123-54',
  'Name: Example: A string title. Variable 2014; 31: 123-54',
  'This can basically be anything!: Example: A string title. Publication 100 2058; 789: 123',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (1998): Example: A string title. What Ever 4, 123-54',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Journey of 2000 miles 54 (6), 123-54',
  'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Some Words. 1999 June;1(6):123-54. Ignore this'
 ],
 re = /^(.*?)\s*(?:\(((?:19|20)\d\d)\)|:)[\s:]*(.*?[?.!])\s*([\w\s]+?)\.?\s*(?:((?:19|20)\d\d)(?:\s+\w+)?)?[.;\s]*(\d+)\s*(?:\(\d+\))?[,:\s]+(\d+(?:-\d+)?)[^\d]*$/,
 res,
 i, j
 output = '<style>caption {background-color: blue; color: white;} th {background-color: lightblue;}</style>';

for (i = 0; i < theStrings.length; i++) {

 res = theStrings[i].match(re);

 output += '<table border="1" style="width:100%">';
 output += '<tr>';
 output += '<caption>The string "' + theStrings[i] + '" ends up as:</caption>';
 output += '<tr><th style="width:30%">Title 1</th><th style="width:10%">Year</th><th style="width:30%">Title 2</th><th style="width:10%">Value 4</th><th style="width:10%">Value 5</th><th style="width:10%">Value 6</th></tr>';
 output += '<td>' + res[1] + '</td>';
 output += '<td>' + (res[2] ? res[2] : res[5]) + '</td>';
 output += '<td>' + res[3] + '</td>';
 output += '<td>' + res[4] + '</td>';
 output += '<td>' + res[6] + '</td>';
 output += '<td>' + res[7] + '</td></tr></table><br/>';
}
document.write(output);
```

**Edit**

Comment: *The title ends by a year in parentheses or colon OR dot .*

I haven't completely grasped what the different parts are, but I assume in this case it's the first field we're talking about. (The third field in the examples ends "A string title"...) The regex in it's current form handles year and colon. So to add *dot* to the *field terminators* you could change the `:` in question to `[:.]` allowing either:

```
                          Here: ▼▼▼▼
^(.*?)\s*(?:\(((?:19|20)\d\d)\)|[:.])[\s:]*(.*?[?.!])\s*([\w\s]+?)\.?\s*(?:((?:19|20)\d\d)(?:\s+\w+)?)?[.;\s]*(\d+)\s*(?:\(\d+\))?[,:\s]+(\d+(?:-\d+)?)[^\d]*$
```

Comment: Wow, very complex. It seems to be lightly shorter then the regex of HiDeo

Comment: Not only shorter - it handles variations that the other suggestions can't handle ;)

Comment: That's indeed 23 characters shorter, nice one. The only problem I can think of with this regex is the missing requirements which were in the question before the edits like for example anything can be a title with `.*` in this regex and OP wanted `[characters][comma][space][1-3 uppercase characters]`. If I remember correctly from what OP said, if these requirements are not correct, the regex should failed. Need to know from OP if these requirements are still needed.

Comment: Why should you be strict about years `(?:19|20)\d\d` but don't care about beginning of lines?!

Comment: @revo What do you mean "don't care about beginning of lines"? About the year it's just simple way to avoid **some** possible mismatches - e.g. a title like `Journey of 1000 miles` would confuse the logic without that check.

Comment: @HiDeo I think it is safer to check the complete format, that means, the author names  should be `[characters][comma][space][1-3 uppercase characters]` and optional `et al.` at the end.

Comment: @ClasG I like your regEx. But I don't think you need the 19/20 check. `Journey of 2000 miles` will also work...

Comment: @user3142695 Yeah that's what I thought and suggested to avoid using `.*` like in this answer.

Comment: @HiDeo But ClasG's regex works also if there is a digit in the title or *publication* is a sentence. That makes it in this part more robust. Initially I did not think about that, that's why there is no example string for that in my post.

Comment: @user3142695 As said, the 19/20 check was put there because it a very simple way to avoid **some** mismatches. It's far from bullet proof, but it might help in some cases, and it doesn't cost much to have it there. But no A you'll get from this Q is gonna be even close to a 100%. They'll all be prone to erroneous matches. Anyway... Removing the 19/20 is a cinch. And I still believe this regex is the one handling most variations in the string without failing... Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know, but you can divide the number of steps by 3 like this: https://regex101.com/r/pL3kJ5/1

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to generalize this a bit more if your example input is an indicator of a common string that you'll usually encounter :

```
// Split the string based on parentheses, periods, question-marks and colons
// along with any leading or trailing spaces (i.e. trimming)
var matches = input.split(/\s*[().?:]\s*/);
```

Regular Expressions can generally be nightmares from a readability and maintenance standpoint, so if it's feasible to simplify them, I would recommend it.

**Example**

[image]

```js
var input = "Name I, Some A, More BC (2016) A string title. Publication. 12:123-54";
var matches = input.split(/\s*[()?.:]\s*/);
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
    console.log('[' + i +']:' + ' ' + matches[i]);
}
```

Comment: I like this approach (+1).

Comment: Thanks. But I need to check for matching the exact structure. That's why I need a precise regEx. If the string has not the correct format, I want to abort further processing...

Comment: One approach that you could consider would be to use something like this example to actually split your inputs once you have determined if the input itself is valid (via a larger more exact expression).

Comment: For instance `([\w]+ [A-Z]{1,3},? )+\(\d{4}\)[\w ]+[?.]\s[\w ]+[?.]\s\d+:\d+-\d+` could evaluate your format and then the previous approach could split it.

Comment: What is the advantage to evaluate the format and do a split after that instead of using the same regex for evaluation and splitting (match)? Please have a look at the updated question. I added more detailed examples.

Comment: Complex regular expressions that need to evaluate multiple terms may not be the best at splitting a string. So using a single expression to validate it (using your exact format) and once it is valid, then use an expression to handle splitting out your individual components. With the addition of your other examples, I'm not sure the previous expression still works (that's part of a he reason why I asked about your format initially)

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
([^()]+)\((\d+)\)\s*([^.]+)[.\s]*([^.]+)[.\s]*(\d+):([-\d]+)
```

The capture group numbers correspond to yours, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/bF2zC9/1).

Comment: Great, but as I understand that, it doesn't check for the exact format, right? As example the names aren't checked for correct initials (1-3 characters) and the year has to be 4-digit...

Comment: @user3142695: Does it have to be in `JavaScript` ? PCRE (PHP, Python, C#, ...) offers better possibilities, ie. whitespace mode to explain the structure.

Comment: @user3142695: As your other question was deleted - please provide at least 5 strings that should match and five that must not be matched - any why. Javascript has a very crippled regex engine - the one mentioned for `PHP`, etc. is ***far*** better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following regex:

```
^([A-Za-z-]+ [A-Z]{1,3}(?:, [A-Za-z-]+ [A-Z]{1,3})*(?:, et al\.)?):? (?:\((\d{4})\):? )?([A-Za-z\:\?\. ]+[A-Za-z\?])\.? ([A-Za-z]+)\.? (?:([0-9]+)[A-Za-z ]*; ?)?(\d+) ?(?:\(\d+\))?[\:,] ?([0-9-]+)
```

As the `year` can be swapped at different places, I'm using this code to always fetch the correct `year`:

```
var year = matches[2] || matches[5];
```

You can check the whole script in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysxnpvc1/1/).

This regular expression will give me the following outputs which I think are what you're looking for:

> 'Name I, Some A, More BC (2016) A string title. Illustration. 12:123-54'

```
1: "Name I, Some A, More BC"
2: "2016"
3: "A string title"
4: "Illustration"
5: "12"
6: "123-54"
```

> 'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016) Example: A string title. Publication. 12:123-54'

```
1: "Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC"
2: "2016"
3: "Example: A string title"
4: "Publication"
5: "12"
6: "123-54"
```

> 'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC, et al. (2016) Example: A string title? Publication. 12:123-54'

```
1: "Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC, et al."
2: "2016"
3: "Example: A string title?"
4: "Publication"
5: "12"
6: "123-54"
```

> 'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Illustration 2016; 12: 123-54'

```
1: "Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC"
2: "2016"
3: "Example: A string title"
4: "Illustration"
5: "12"
6: "123-54"
```

> 'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication 2016; 12: 123'

```
1: "Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC"
2: "2016"
3: "Example: A string title"
4: "Publication"
5: "12"
6: "123"
```

> 'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Publication 12, 123-54'

```
1: "Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC"
2: "2016"
3: "Example: A string title"
4: "Publication"
5: "12"
6: "123-54"
```

> 'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Publication 12 (6), 123-54'

```
1: "Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC"
2: "2016"
3: "Example: A string title"
4: "Publication"
5: "12"
6: "123-54"
```

> 'Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication. 2016 June;12(6):123-54. Ignore this'

```
1: "Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC"
2: "2016"
3: "Example: A string title"
4: "Publication"
5: "12"
6: "123-54"
```

Comment: `Publication` is also a variable string, not a fixed word. The string is ending by dot or a space with followed digit.

Comment: And the only thing I change for the example string is, that there could be `, et al.` at the end of authors. So authors are ending by space without comma or `, et al.`.

Comment: I modified the regex to match these new criteria, the #1 & #4 example string to reflect the `Publication` being a variable string and the #3 example to have `, et al.`. The fiddle is also updated to a new version.

Comment: Beware! `[A-z]` doesn't match what you think, it's a range, take a look at the ascii table.

Comment: Ho, thanks for the reminder, I always forget these 6 symbols between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this clumsy looking regex for capturing various components:

```
/^((?:,? *[A-Za-z.-]+ [A-Za-z]{1,3})+)[ :.,]+(?:\((\d+)\)[ :]+)?([a-zA-Z]+: [a-zA-Z ]+[?]?)[. ]+([A-Za-z]+)[. ;\dA-Za-z]+?(\d+)(?:[:,]| *\()[: \d,)]*?(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:[ .]|$)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wB3wU4/6)

Comment: But this doesn't take care of the order or amount of matching parts, right? I need to check if the string exactly matches and then get the parts out of that. So, wouldn't be Jan's approach better - if it would check a bit more precise?

Comment: ok in that case try my updated regex for following specific ordering of components

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Check my updated regex. This satisfies all the given samples in your question and shows all the capturing groups on right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

### Update #1

*There are lots of answers and so I should provide some comparisons as well*

### What do you have for me?

```
^([\w-]+ [A-Z]{1,3}(?:, [\w-]+ [a-zA-Z]{1,3}\.?)*)[ :](?:\((\d+)\)| ?([\w]+)):? ?([ \w]+)[.:?]? ?([ \w]+)?[.:?]? ?([A-Za-z]+)?[.:?]? ?([\d]+) ?([a-zA-Z]+)?[,;:]? ?(?:\(([\d-]+)\),?|([\d-]+)):? ?(?:\((\d+)\)[,:]|([\d-]+))? ?([\d-]+)?
```

*FYI it's 232 characters long.*

### Does it work?

If inputs are similar to those in original post or are specified as you said in some comments, it does work. [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH0xF9/2)

### So lengthy, is it called a real RegEx?

I don't consider it as a Regular Expression. It uses the syntax but is not much more than a programming if/else condition. It's like climbing a ladder which may have some broken rungs. But that is a way you need to solve your problem.

### Why should I choose yours?

I don't know. That's your choice. But I'm going to do a benchmarking test on answers that can fulfill your need.

- Input string:

```
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016) Example: A string title. Publication. 12:123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC, et al. (2016) Example: A string title? Publication. 12:123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication 2016; 12: 123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication 2016; 12: 123
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Publication 12, 123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2016): Example: A string title. Publication 12 (6), 123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC: Example: A string title. Publication. 2016 June;12(6):123-54. Ignore this
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC (2050) Example: A string title. Placeholder. 55:123-54
Name I, Some-Thing A, More BC, et al. (2016) Example: A string title? Word. 22:123-54
```

- Number of iterations: 50 x 1000
- Flags on: `multi-line`

#### Results:

@HiDeo's RegEx:

```
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9

Elapsed Time:    10.75 s,   10753.42 ms,   10753415 µs
```

@anubhava's RegEx:

```
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9

Elapsed Time:    9.28 s,   9277.62 ms,   9277621 µs
```

@ClasG's RegEx:

```
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9

Elapsed Time:    8.86 s,   8864.05 ms,   8864050 µs
```

@revo's RegEx:

```
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9

Elapsed Time:    7.02 s,   7024.97 ms,   7024972 µs
```

As it is demonstrated, all performing times are very close to each other. So you don't have a hard time to select one.

*Thanks @sln for his time saving and great software [RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com/) that recently I began to work with.*

Comment: Nice comparaison, didn't know about this little tool, thanks. We really need more precision from @user3142695 regarding the requirements that were stripped from the question, for the title for instance, your regex will match even if the title start with a `comma` for example.

Comment: So for that reason I updated my RegEx (as well as benchmark) in regards to OP's RegEx. @HiDeo

Comment: Then you can merge 3rd and 4th capturing groups into one. @user3142695

Comment: It's fast n'all... But if you take the example strings I have in my regex101 demo you'll see that it cant handle all of them. I know - I made them up, but we've already heard from OP that they're plausible scenarios.

Comment: I went with OP's RegEx and you went with something more flexible and this flexibility costs. Check how many steps your RegEx takes to find matches by switching to PCRE flavor on regex101 which I don't think it is a need. Adding extra conditions is much more better than `.*` and its family. @ClasG

Comment: I don't see anything in the Q mentioning that performance is a factor. That obviously doesn't mean it doesn't matter, and I "always" strive to make anything I do as effective as possible. But... if you take the mentioned example and run your regex it finishes in 3038 steps. If you run mine, without the 19/20 test, it takes 4749. I.e. mine is 63+ percent "slower" than yours. Now, your fails 3 out of 14 tests, roughly 21 percent, mine none. There's the fact - now it's just up to OP to decide which is best suited for the task

Comment: We shouldn't rely on OP to whether offer an acceptable performing solution, never, and I am not talking to OP but you. If OP sees failing matches with my RegEx then it means he was not clear about provided examples in his question. He may modify it and ping me. And as I remember yours will take x3 extra unnecessary steps compare to others with input going larger and at least for me, it counts a lot. @ClasG